# How do Little and Big Endian look if I want padding to 4 bytes?

Tags: c#, .net, endianness

Somehow I'm having a brainfart and can't figure out proper big and little endian representations. I have a bytestream in which a 32-Bit Integer is stored.

The Integer is 1000 decimal, which is 0x03E8 hexadecimal. In little Endian, this would be stored as `E8 03` when represented as two bytes.

I assumed that if I want 4 byte padding, it would be stored as `00 00 E8 03`. However, when I use the BitConverter, I get strange results:

```
// true
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian);

var bytes = new byte[4] { 0x00, 0x00, 0xE8, 0x03 };
var convertedInt = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes,0);
// 65536000 ?!
Console.WriteLine(convertedInt);

var inputInt = 1000;
var convertedBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(inputInt);
// 4 Bytes: e8 03 00 00
Console.WriteLine("{0} Bytes: {1:x2} {2:x2} {3:x2} {4:x2}", convertedBytes.Length,
        convertedBytes[0],  convertedBytes[1],
        convertedBytes[2],  convertedBytes[3]);
```

This looks like BitConverter is broken. [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de8fssa4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) clearly says:

> The order of bytes in the array returned by the GetBytes method depends on whether the computer architecture is little-endian or big-endian.

So, am I misunderstanding how Little Endian works, is BitConverter broken, or do I do something wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So, am I misunderstanding how Little Endian works

Yup. Little endian means the least significant parts come first - so 1000 would actually be

```
Little endian: E8 03 00 00
Big endian:    00 00 03 E8
```

The least significant byte of the number is E8, so surely it should go at *one* end or the other - little-endian representation puts it at the start; big-endian representation puts it at the end. Your suggested representation of `00 00 E8 03` puts it in the middle. According to the [Wikipedia Endianness page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), that sort of representation *does* exist, but only rarely - this is called mixed-endian or middle-endian.

Code to confirm:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var bytes = new byte[4] { 0xE8, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00 };
        var convertedInt = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
        Console.WriteLine(convertedInt); // 1000
    }
}
```